# Highlighted overlay in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tooltip, overlay

Is there any way to highlight the area with overlay like below image? I need to show like this tooltip for the users who are using the app first time.

[image]

Comment: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/02/23/overlayview-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Have you find a solution in the link I provided? Please update.